# How to only get un common records from mysql

Tags: mysql

Now I am using this query, but it is showing me both dublicate & non duplicate columns, I only want to get non duplicate colums,

```
<?

$queryy=mysql_query("SELECT   
 mybb_posts.pid, mybb_posts.subject,mybb_posts.message,mybb_posts.tid,
mybb_attachments.pid,mybb_attachments.aid
FROM mybb_posts
INNER JOIN mybb_attachments
USING(pid,pid)
ORDER  BY  `aid` DESC
LIMIT 7")or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

while ($lista=mysql_fetch_array($queryy))
{
echo '


            <img src="attachment.php?aid='.$lista["aid"].'   " alt="" />
                <h4><a href="#" >'.$lista["subject"].'</a></h4>

            ';

}

?>
```

Comment: Please show an example of actual results and desired results.

Comment: okay make it simple, just tell the query to select non- duplicate records from a table

Answer (score 0):

Try using DISTINCT in your select.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
posts.pid, 
posts.subject,
posts.message,
posts.tid, 
attach.pid,
attach.aid 
FROM mybb_posts post
INNER JOIN mybb_attachments attach
ON mybb_posts.pid = mybb_attachments.pid
ORDER  BY  `aid` DESC LIMIT 7
```

This DISTINCT query should return only the results that are unique where the PID matches in both columns. If there are more than one entity related to that PID it will insert another row.

The group by can only be used when you use an aggregate function on an entity. For example: SUM(attach.aid) in your SELECT will allow you to group by PID

If you are returning a bunch of different integers for one record, and don't want the duplicate rows you can use the group by to sum the results into one row...

Here is a reference that describes my prose.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/29/sql-server-difference-between-distinct-and-group-by-distinct-vs-group-by/

Comment: Or you could use a GROUP BY, if you are using aggregate functions, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I have tried DISTICNT but didn't work, and group by how to use that ? just tell the simple query to select non dupliacate recods

Comment: the query you posted is not working , please give me a solution :(

Comment: are you running the query in mySQL to see if it returns the results you want? What do you mean by not working?